# deprecation of apply decorator

Tags: python

There was a beautiful way to organize class property in frame of one function, by using the apply decorator.

```
class Example(object):
    @apply
    def myattr():
        doc = """This is the doc string."""

        def fget(self):
            return self._half * 2

        def fset(self, value):
            self._half = value / 2

        def fdel(self):
            del self._half

        return property(**locals())
```

But now apply has been deprecated.

Is there any possibility to achieve such simplicity and readability for property, with new, came instead “extended call syntax”?

---

My approach is same as Anurag’s, but, I don’t now witch one is better, please look:

```
def prop(f):

    return property(**f())

class A(object):

    @prop
    def myattr():

        def fget(self):
            return self._myattr

        def fset(self, value):
            self._myattr = value 

        return locals()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there any possibility to achieve such simplicity and readability for property

The new Python 2.6 way is:

```
@property
def myattr(self):
    """This is the doc string."""
    return self._half * 2

@myattr.setter
def myattr(self, value):
    self._half = value / 2

@myattr.deleter
def myattr(self):
    del self._half
```

Comment: I didn't know this and I like it very way. The 'apply' magic above was so unreadable I didn't quite know what the question was about.

I knew @property and use it a lot, but .setter and .deleter are new to me and look great (self-documenting code) :)

Comment: You're missing self in the arguments to the getter, no?

Comment: @JacekKonieczny - you're wrong, this usage of @apply IS readable, provided that you know a thing or two about decorators and higher-order functions (like `apply`). What's more it's simple and elegant way to use closures in Python - you know, in the example OP posted you could introduce some variables shared by getter/setter/deleter functions which would be truly private and would not pollute the namespace of a class! Just use your imagination instead of rejecting things you don't know yet.

Answer (score 2):

:) that is a clever user of apply, though i am not sure if there are any pitfalls?

anyway you can do this

```
class Example(object):
    def myattr():
        doc = """This is the doc string."""

        def fget(self):
            return self._half * 2

        def fset(self, value):
            self._half = value / 2

        def fdel(self):
            del self._half

        return property(**locals())
    myattr = myattr()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always write your own:

```
def apply(f, a):
    return f(*a)
```

However, I'm not quite sure I see the benefit of using `apply` as a decorator in this way. What's the use case?

Comment: I want to place declarations of fget/fset methods in scope of one function. Is there any other solution, except apply decorator?